# Set Retry Option for EventGrid EventGridPublisherClient

Tags: c#, publish, azure-eventgrid

I would like to set retry as part of ClientOptions while initializing EventGridPublisherClient. I see that we can pass EventGridPublisherClientOptions which inherits ClientOptions but that read only get property and i dont see we can set as part of constructor as well. Is there a way that we can set retry. We are trying to see if we can retry whe nwe recevie 429 or any transient error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
            var options = new EventGridPublisherClientOptions();
            options.Retry.Mode = Azure.Core.RetryMode.Exponential;
            options.Retry.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            options.Retry.MaxRetries = 5;

            var client = new EventGridPublisherClient(
                new Uri(_eventGridConfiguration.TopicEndpoint),
                new AzureKeyCredential(_eventGridConfiguration.SasKey),
                options);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).